# Multi Output Regression but num of objects to predict vary per sample

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, ai-design, time-series

so recently I came across a problem of predicting the positions of objects from a pulse wave. My biggest concern here is that for each data sample, the number of objects varies. I know that this should be treated as a Multi-output regression problem, but how do I cater to the variation in the number of objects per sample? Also, what would fare better, XGboost or some neural network architecture?

Comment: look for objects detection papers in the CV literature, this was one of the early problems they had